# How can I turn off column sorting in Django-admin tables or specify WHICH columns are sortable?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there an easy way to turn off sortability for for some/all columns in the django admin and/or specify *which* columns are sortable?

I know I can manually disable sorting via javascript, but that's kinda hacky, and I was hoping there was a better or built-in way.

I'm trying to implement drag/drop ordering of admin lists similar to this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2870/, but it doesn't make sense to have drag/drop ordering  if the table is sorted by other-than the position column.  The table I'm doing this for will never be a large table, so there's no reason a user would ever need to sort by other-than the position column, and allowing it to sort by another column would just add confusion.

Comment: One (hacky) way is to override the `change_list` template and disable `a` for fields you want to remove ordering from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an elegant way to do this.

You can turn it off in the back end by using a custom ChangeList and overriding the `get_ordering_field` method to return None for the fields that you don't want to be sortable.  I haven't tested, but it looks like that will make the admin disregard them if a request to sort on that field ends up in the request.  You could then either override the `change_list_results.html` template that renders the table headers or use some JS to remove the CSS/Javascript parts.

Alternately, you could create methods on your model or your admin class that shadow the columns you don't want to be sortable, not set their admin_order_field value, and use only those in your `list_display`.  That doesn't require changing as much of the built-in admin, but it's kind of absurd.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I had found this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2580/, which is similar to your suggestion. However, that snippet, as written, doesn't work (at least not in the version of django I'm using). Your suggestion to override get_ordering_field(), rather than get_ordering(), does the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm still going to need to manually remove the styles and javascript, but at least it prevents the sorting.

Comment: Just eyeballing it, I think the template edits would be simple - the built in one has a bunch of 'if header.sortable' tags, and you could just delete everything in 'em.  Unfortunately, that `sortable` attribute is set in a template tag and short-circuits any fancy logic if the field is actually a model field, so you can't easily tell it that things are not sortable.

Answer (score 7):

For those who come here to find out other solutions than prescribed in the above, If your `Admin Model Class` has a subclass of `ModelAdmin` or `admin.ModelAdmin`, there's a subclass variable that can be referred to filter out or to indicate which fields that can be opted for sorting data in columns.

Here's the [documentation link.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.sortable_by)

But here's the content so far.

> **ModelAdmin.sortable_by**
> By default, the change list page allows sorting by all model fields (and callables that have the admin_order_field property) specified in list_display.
>
> If you want to disable sorting for some columns, set sortable_by to a collection (e.g. list, tuple, or set) of the subset of list_display that you want to be sortable. An empty collection disables sorting for all columns.
>
> If you need to specify this list dynamically, implement a get_sortable_by() method instead.

**Application**

- For instance, we don't want to provide sorting to `associateId` because of various reasons. To avoid sorting on a particular field. Just exclude that field and re-declare other fields.

```py
class AssociateAttributeFields(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "associateId",
        "isAllowed",
        "staffRole",
        "dtCreated",
    )
    sortable_by = (
        "isAllowed",
        "staffRole",
        "dtCreated",
    )
    # Can also be the following to avoid being redundant...
    # sortable_by = list_display[1:]
```

**Output**
For clarity purposes.
[image: Demo]

Answer (score 4):

I have done this by replacing the field name in the `list_display` tuple with the name of a method which I then implement on the model. For example, to disable sorting on the "title" field on your model, instead of doing this in "admin.py":

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title')
```

use this:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title_for_admin')
```

Then in your "models.py":

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def title_for_admin(self):
        return self.title

    # To keep 'Title' as the column header in the admin
    title_for_admin.short_description = "Title"
```

This should produce an admin with the "Title" column as normal, but it is no longer sortable.

This is not a great solution for disabling sorting on all columns or even on many columns if your model has a lot of fields, but it works all right for disabling sorting on one or two columns.

Comment: easy solution, without touching any deeper internals. nice.

Answer (score 2):

I did a monkeypatch to always disable column sorting.

```
# monkeypatch: override the original `result_headers` template function
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags import admin_list
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import result_headers
orig_result_headers = result_headers

def result_headers(cl):
    for header in orig_result_headers(cl):
        header['sortable'] = False
        yield header

admin_list.result_headers = result_headers
```

But you could do a custom monkeypatch for your needs.

```
# model admin
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c')
    list_display_sortable = ('field_b', 'field_c')

# monkeypatch: override the original `result_headers` template function
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags import admin_list
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import result_headers
orig_result_headers = result_headers

def result_headers(cl):
    sortable_idx = []
    sortable_fields = getattr(cl.model_admin, 'list_display_sortable', ())
    for field_name in cl.list_display:
        sortable_idx.append(field_name in sortable_fields)
    for i, header in enumerate(orig_result_headers(cl)):
        header['sortable'] = sortable_idx[i]
        yield header

admin_list.result_headers = result_headers
```

Tested with Django 1.10

Comment: Great!  I tested this with Django 1.11 and work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I made a shortcut for [nttaylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257174/4719118), you can create a decorator like this

```
from six.moves import reduce

def list_property(field_name, **kwargs):
    def _from_property(obj):
        rv = reduce(getattr, field_name.split("."), obj)
        return rv() if callable(rv) else rv

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(_from_property, key, value)
    return _from_property
```

and use this in your modeladmin:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [list_property("title", short_description=_("..."))]
```

you can make this decorator more intelligent by assign field's verbose_name to decorated property.